# When to use memory and storage in the perimeter of a function in Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

hello to all my fellow block chain developers, i am currently in process of learning solidity. I encountered these keywords called memory and storage. according to the tutorial that i am following right now, memory variable is only stored during execution of the function, on the other hand storage variable will persist even after the execution of the function. I am a little confused on when to use memory and storage keyword and if i should be using it in future contracts. also in other stack overflow question i saw that it is also used when you want to return something from the function is it necessary?

for example in function below i am using memory to store in _data variable.

```
    function test_storage(string memory _data) public{
        data = _data;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure, I can help you with that.

In Solidity, the `memory` keyword is used to declare variables that are stored in the Ethereum Virtual Machine's (EVM) memory. The `storage` keyword is used to declare variables that are stored in the contract's storage.

The main difference between memory and storage is that memory is temporary, while storage is persistent. This means that variables declared in memory will be erased after the function in which they are declared finishes executing, while variables declared in storage will persist until they are explicitly deleted.

In general, you should use `memory` for variables that are only needed for the duration of a single function call, and `storage` for variables that need to persist between function calls.

In your example, you are using `memory` to store the `_data` variable. This is because you only need the `_data` variable for the duration of the `test_storage` function. After the `test_storage` function finishes executing, the `_data` variable will be erased.

If you wanted to store the `_data` variable in storage, you would need to declare it using the `storage` keyword. For example:

```
function test_storage(string storage _data) public {
  data = _data;
}
```

In this case, the `_data` variable would be stored in the contract's storage, and it would persist after the `test_storage` function finishes executing.

As for whether or not you should use `memory` or `storage` in your future contracts, it depends on the specific needs of your contract. If you only need a variable for the duration of a single function call, then you should use `memory`. If you need a variable to persist between function calls, then you should use `storage`.